# Trying to justify headers of table

Tags: tables

What I'm trying to do is put a block of text in the upper left and lower right of a table. I cannot use a caption or block of text, because the tables I have span more than one page. And the statement has to appear again when the table continues to a second page.

The sample block of code I am working with is as follows:

```
\documentclass[amsfonts]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{threeparttablex}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\nofiles
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,urlcolor=blue}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\definecolor{Gray}{gray}{0.85}
\begin{document}
\subsection*{Sample Table:}
\begin{ThreePartTable}
\begin{longtable}[H]{|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
\multicolumn{6}{l}{Upper mark} \\
\endhead
\multicolumn{6}{r}{Lower mark} \\
\endfoot
\hline
\rowcolor{Gray}
Col One & Col Two & Col Three & Col Four & Col Five & Col Six\\\hline
{{ var.one }} & {{ var.two }} & {{ var.three }} & {{ var.four }} & {{ var.five }} & {{ var.six }} \\\hline
\end{longtable}
\end{ThreePartTable}
\end{document}
```

[image: Sample table created]

Any ideas on how to get this working?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! I've taken the liberty of adding a couple of instructions -- essentially, loading the `hyperref` and `xcolor` packages -- so as to make your code compilable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The double curly braces around some of the cell contents and the `[H]` location specifier are both unneeded (and possibly counterproductive). At any rate, the following modified form of your code seems to achieve your objective.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{threeparttable,threeparttablex}
\usepackage{booktabs,amsfonts}
%\nofiles
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}  %% new
\definecolor{Gray}{gray}{0.85}
\usepackage{hyperref}       %% new
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,urlcolor=blue}
\begin{document}
\subsection*{Sample Table}
\begin{ThreePartTable}
\begin{longtable}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
\multicolumn{6}{l}{Upper mark} \\
\hline
\endhead
\hline
\multicolumn{6}{r}{Lower mark} \\
\endfoot
\rowcolor{Gray}
Col One & Col Two & Col Three & Col Four & Col Five & Col Six\\
\hline
 var.one  &  var.two  &  var.three  &  var.four  &  var.five  &  var.six  \\
\end{longtable}
\end{ThreePartTable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Double curly braces were artifacts of a parser program I use and stripped down for this. I've made the proper changes, thank you for your help. The nofiles in particular is what messed the generation up.

Answer (score 0):

I hope that I understand you right. Try using the `longtable` package. I tried to copy your table with the following code using `\multicolumn`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{preview}

\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{p{.15\textwidth}p{.15\textwidth}p{.15\textwidth}p{.15\textwidth}p{.15\textwidth}p{.15\textwidth}}
 \toprule
 \multicolumn{6}{c}{Upper mark}\\ \midrule
 \endfirsthead
 \multicolumn{6}{c}{Upper mark}\\ \midrule
 \endhead
 \midrule \multicolumn{6}{c}{Lower mark}\\ \bottomrule
 \endfoot
 \midrule \multicolumn{6}{c}{Lower mark}\\
 \bottomrule
 \endlastfoot
 %
 Col One & Col Two & Col Three & Col Four & Col Five & Col Six\\
 var.one & var.two & var.three & var.four & var.five & var.six
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

You will get the part before `\endfirsthead` on the first head, the part between this and `\endhead`for every head afterwards; the same with `\endfoot`and `\endlastfoot`. The code produces the following table:
[image: table using longtable and booktabs]

I hope, that this will help you.

Comment: The OP *is* using the `longtable` package and its eponymous environment. What he/she is trying to accomplish is to get the "Upper mark" string left-aligned and the "Lower mark" string right-aligned.

Comment: I see that you have the right answer then. Using `\multicolumn`with r or l for left- or right-aligned.

Comment: Mico was correct, but thank you for the help. Taking some of your modifications in to make the code easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

It will produce the desired result if you compile `3 times`. Typically, longtable requires at least 2 compilations for its computations. Here is the result after 2 compilations:

[image]

and after 3:

[image]

Comment: I would not have guessed that. It works, thank you for the help. I am using this with a program, so I generate the document, mv it into another folder, and delete the excess files.